# Control frequency of Javascript http calls to avoid HTTP302 errors

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting a 302 (too many requests) response error with the following code:

```
        for (link in linkArray) {
            console.log(linkArray[link]);
            var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
            while (currentTime + 100 >= new Date().getTime()) {
            }
            http.get(linkArray[link], function(res) {
                console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode); // <======= Here's the status code
            }).on('error', function(e) {
                console.error(e);
            });
        }
```

I added the `while (currentTime + 100 >= new Date().{}` to try and slow down the requests but that has simply slows down the `console.log()`  I still get the 302 errors.  Please note, if I make the http calls outside the for loop, I get http 200 responses which is what I expect at the moment.

How to a control the flow of calls within the for loop?

I've also tried:

```
        for (link in linkArray) {
            console.log(linkArray[link]);

            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                http.get(linkArray[link], function(res) {
                    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode); // <======= Here's the status code
                }).on('error', function(e) {
                    console.error(e);
                }, 100);
            });
        }
```

**EDIT**  Full function.

```
function http404Promise() { 
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var linkArray = new Array()
        db.sequelize.query(photoQuery, {
            replacements: queryParams
        }).spread(function(makeSiteMap) {
            makeSiteMap.forEach(function(obj) {
                var siteLink = hostname + 'photo/' + obj.img_id
                linkArray.push(siteLink)
                //console.log(siteLink);
            });

            resolve(linkArray);

            http.get(linkArray[1], function(res) {
                console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode); // <======= Here's the status code
                if (res.statusCode == 302) {
                    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
                    while (currentTime + 1000 >= new Date().getTime()) {
                    }
                }
            }).on('error', function(e) {
                console.error(e);
            });

            /*
            for (link in linkArray) {
                console.log(linkArray[link]);
                var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
                while (currentTime + 100 >= new Date().getTime()) {
                }

                http.get(linkArray[link], function(res) {
                    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode); // <======= Here's the status code
                }).on('error', function(e) {
                    console.error(e);
                });
            }
            */

            for (link in linkArray) {
                console.log(linkArray[link]);

                timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                    http.get(linkArray[link], function(res) {
                        console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode); // <======= Here's the status code
                    }).on('error', function(e) {
                        console.error(e);
                    }, link*100);
                });
            }

        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you considered a request loop ('too many redirects') in your HTTP server? What happens when you make the request manually? (cURL or Postman)

Comment: @Airwavezx I'm sorry I don't really understand your question.  I know I don't have redirects at this stage because I'm running the site on my PC and I know every request I'm making is direct to a URL that will give a 200 response

Comment: @HentryM What happens when you make the request manually? Does it also return 302?

Comment: @Airwavezx - if I do `curl http://127.0.0.1:8081/photo/0091EB4FC5` it returns the html

Comment: What HTTP server are you running?

Comment: I'm running nodejs with express.

Comment: Have you tried `promises` approach? I'm kind of shooting in the air hoping to hit something here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/promises

Comment: second version of your code will apply equal delay for your requests.
as really short'n'dirty solution you can just set delay depending on index: `50 * i` instead of constant value 100

Comment: @skyboyer - just tried, same issue

Comment: @Airwavezx - it is actually embedded within a Promise.  I'm just editing to show you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution

```
var http404Promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var linkArray = new Array()

        db.sequelize.query(photoQuery, {
            replacements: queryParams
        }).spread(function(photoLinks) {
            photoLinks.forEach(function(obj) {
                var siteLink = hostname + 'photo/' + obj.img_id
                linkArray.push(siteLink)

                //console.log(siteLink);
            });

            resolve(linkArray);
        });
    });


http404Promise.then(function(linkArray) {
    linkArray.forEach(function(element, index) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(element);
            http.get(element, function(res) {
                console.log(element);
                console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode); // <======= Here's the status code
            }).on('error', function(e) {
                console.log(element);
                console.error(e);
                process.exit();
            })
        }, index * 50);
    })    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have different alternatives:

1. make all request run in sequence while currently they all run in parallel(or send requests subset-after-subset)
2. re-run any request once it gets 302 in response
3. make nodejs place extra requests to some kind of queue instead of dropping it with 302
4. create "bulk" version for your endpoint so you will be able to request whole list at once

I believe #4 is the better than other.

Comment: how do I make them run in sequence?

Comment: there is no easy way. you should write the code that will send next xhr from the inside of previous call's `.then()` section.